# silicon image 3512 SATA card & BSOD

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, sata

I updated the BIOS on my SiI3512 SATA card this morning because of some boot issues with Windows not detecting the card.  Now my WinXP BSODs every time I boot, no matter if I choose safe mode or normal startup.  The BSOD happens so fast that I can't see the specific driver.sys file thats causing the problem.  But, I'm almost positive it will be the 3512.  If I use the WinXP cd-rom and try to use the recovery console doesn't detect the drive.  I can get into the card's BIOS and all looks ok.  So here are my 2 questions.

1. Is there a way to exclude a specific driver on boot?
2. I don't mind re-installing XP, but if I put the drive on another machines SATA will it be readable so I can copy files?  It wasn't raided, but I read that some cards write proprietary stuff to the drive.

**Updated:**
The right question is, why is my 3512 SATA card causing Windows XP to BSOD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silicon Image bios files come in 2 flavors, a "Raid" version and a "Base" version.  I had inadvertantly flashed the RAID version.  This is what was causing the BSOD.  I downloaded [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org/) and added the [SII3512](http://www.siliconimage.com/support/searchresults.aspx?pid=29&cat=15) to the CD image and burned the CD.  I then followed the instructions in the bios update documentation to reflash the controller with the "BASE" version of the bios.  And now I'm typing this answer on the machine that was BSOD earlier.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the BIOS update changed the settings from IDE to AHCI?

and your Windows Setup doesn't detect the drive because XP doesn't have native support for SATA  controllers, you'll have to load the drivers manually via F6 (requires a floppy drive) or slipstream the drivers into the installation CD.

Comment: Thanks Molly, but I did add the drivers via F6.  It just doesn't see the drive.  I'm thinking I flashed the "Raid" version of the bios instead of the "Link" version.  Checking that now.

Comment: you do that and i'll grab a cup of coffee :)